Why can't Python find Matplotlib after installing Manim (in Windows 11)?
I am using Windows 11 on an HP laptop, purchased August 2024. I have installed Python, then added matplotlib (using the command line from PowerShell) and it seemed to be working (In PowerShell I simply typed python -m pip install matplotlib but note that now I have also tried python3.13 -m pip install matplotlib which was suggested by another question, but the console just said that python3.13 (my version) was not a command). I could run a simple program from w3schools.com using matplotlib.
Then I installed Manim using the Chocolatey package manager (as recommended for the Manim community version). This was by typing: choco install manimce. Now I can't use matplotlib anymore. I can download the package using pip, but the following code won't run:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.array([35, 25, 25, 15])
mylabels = ["Apples", "Bananas", "Cherries", "Dates"]

plt.pie(y, labels = mylabels)
plt.show() 

I have tried running this from the code editor and clicking "run" from the menu options. My editor is called "IDLE", which I have used for every piece of code I have run.
The output from the code: import sys; print(sys.path) is as follows:

['C:/<MYSTUFF>/<MY OWN PROGRAMS>/Python code', 'C:\\Python312\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Python312\\python312.zip', 'C:\\Python312\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python312\\Lib', 'C:\\Python312', 'C:\\Users\\<MY USERNAME>\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\tools\\Manim\\Lib\\site-packages']

So whilst I use the command line for installing packages, I am not running any of these programs from the command line, just the code editor. Then the shell for my IDLE editor reports this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\MYFOLDERSETC\python tester 2.py", line 1, in <module>
import matplotlib as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

The output for the command python -m pip freeze is as follows:

click==8.1.7
cloup==3.0.5
colorama==0.4.6
contourpy==1.3.1
cycler==0.12.1
decorator==5.1.1
fonttools==4.55.2
glcontext==3.0.0
isosurfaces==0.1.2
kiwisolver==1.4.7
manim==0.18.1
ManimPango==0.6.0
mapbox_earcut==1.0.2
markdown-it-py==3.0.0
matplotlib==3.9.3
mdurl==0.1.2
moderngl==5.12.0
moderngl-window==3.0.3
networkx==3.4.2
numpy==2.1.3
packaging==24.2
pillow==11.0.0
pycairo==1.27.0
pydub==0.25.1
pyglet==2.0.20
PyGLM==2.7.3
Pygments==2.18.0
pyparsing==3.2.0
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
rich==13.9.4
scipy==1.14.1
screeninfo==0.8.1
setuptools==75.6.0
six==1.17.0
skia-pathops==0.8.0.post2
srt==3.5.3
svgelements==1.9.6
tqdm==4.67.1
typing_extensions==4.12.2
watchdog==6.0.0
wheel==0.45.

I have tried reinstalling matplotlib from the command line, but the same thing happens each time. I can use numpy to generate simple random numbers, so something is still working. I have tried all the solutions from similar questions on SO, but nothing changes.
I used Chocolatey to install Manim, and tried using it to install matplotlib, but it wouldn't install. I previously have installed all packages (including matplotlib) from the command line) using pip.
What is going wrong, and how can I fix this?

What is the output of pip show matplotlib?

IMO, this is where virtual environments come in handy. It is highly recommended that you use virtual environments to manage your projects. So you know you're installing packages into an isolated environment rather than globally which can cause issues especially if you have multiple python versions.

How many versions of python do you have? Run py -0p in a terminal session to confirm

It won't accept "py -0p" from the command line. Not sure what's happening there. pip show matplotlib gives the version etc. with lots of detail, as in: "Name: matplotlib
Version: 3.9.3
Summary: Python plotting package" (etc)

I should add that somehow, mysteriously, it is working now. I don't know what I did, but it seemed to fix itself when I ran the command "python" from the command line. I don't know why that helped, because I already had everything running, or so I thought, since I am running from IDLE, not the command line. If anyone can give information on anything related to the question, that will help other people, and I also would dearly love to know what went on (since a similar problem is bound to crop up).
